# Arabic font Amiri misaligned output

Tags: luatex, arabic, arabtex, arabluatex

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[voc]{arabluatex}
\begin{document}
 \arb{fa.dlaTuN dAllaTuN}
\end{document}
```

Why do I get misaligned "shadda" and "fatha" (in the word "dAllaTuN)?

I think the package `arablualatex` auto-loads the Amiri font. I tried the latest version of Amiri downloaded from the GitHub page, same result. I have tried many other Arabic fonts, except *AdobeArabic-Regular*, most of them had the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MWE give a correct result with `Renderer = HarfBuzz` option added to Amiri font, I think the bug is introduced few weeks ago (I can't find exactly what package produce the issue).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[voc]{arabluatex}
\begin{document}

\renewfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Renderer = HarfBuzz]{Amiri}

\Huge
 \arb{fa.dlaTuN dAllaTuN}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, Harfbuzz is needed for quite some time.  One other way is to load it globally, like so: `\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Harfbuzz}`, below `\usepackage{fontspec}`.